# From what words is chipageddon formed?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I googled it but couldn't find any results.

Today, chips are in everything from PlayStation 5s and toothbrushes to washing machines and alarm clocks. But there’s not enough to go around — it’s a multifaceted issue that shows no signs of abating, leading some to call the current crisis “chipageddon.”

Source: https://www.cnbc.com/2021/05/12/the-global-chip-shortage-could-last-until-2023-.html

Comment: What Old Brixtonian said! Have a look at [this Archyde article](https://www.archyde.com/chip-armageddon-already-causes-everything-from-a-shortage-of-video-games-to-geopolitical-disputes-technology/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a [portmanteau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portmanteau) of "chip", in this case referring to computer chips, and "Armageddon" a word originally coming from religious conceptions of the end of the world but now widely adopted for ever less significant disasters.

The use of -ageddon or -magaeddon as a suffix to describe some kind of shortage, disaster, or emergency is quite common, as is the alternative -pocalypse. This results in words such as carmageddon, snowmageddon, or snowpocalypse. Usually this form is used [semi-humorously or cynically](https://www.cjr.org/analysis/portmanteau_lesson.php).

Comment: I like [***Chipocalypse***](https://bigcitygreens.fandom.com/wiki/Chipocalypse_Now) better! :)